# how to fix the problem of the missing color pieces in the colorbox in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I met a problem that when I draw a map using gnuplot, there would be a colorbox near the map which looks very weird. I blew up the colorbox and found that there were pieces with missing color, the picture is below. How can I fill the color for the colorbox?
[image: colorboxpicture]

Here are the terminal type and the palette I used in in gnuplot.

```
set terminal postscript portrait color enhanced 12
set palette defined (-6.0 "#1B66B1",\
                     -4.8 "#1B66B1",\
                     -4.8 "#2A85DF",\
                     -3.6 "#2A85DF",\
                     -3.6 "#5FA3E7",\
                     -2.4 "#5FA3E7",\
                     -2.4 "#95C2EF",\
                     -1.2 "#95C2EF",\
                     -1.2 "#C9E0F7",\
                     -0.120000 "#C9E0F7",\
                     0.0 "#FFFFFF",\
                     0.0 "#FFFFFF",\
                     0.120000 "#F6D5CB",\
                     1.2 "#F6D5CB",\
                     1.2 "#EDAB96",\
                     2.4 "#EDAB96",\
                     2.4 "#E48062",\
                     3.6 "#E48062",\
                     3.6 "#DC562E",\
                     4.8 "#DC562E",\
                     4.8  "#AE3F1E",\
                     6.0  "#AE3F1E")
```

Comment: Please provide more information.  What gnuplot terminal type?  I take it this is from a screenshot?  To me it looks like the colorbox rectangles are partially transparent.  Is this because you have use something like `set style fill transparent solid 0.5`?  Are colored areas in your map showing this same effect? Please also show the `set palette` command that defined the palette being used.

Comment: @Ethan Hi, the effects only showed in colorbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ps file has no gaps. If you export it to a png, you may get some artifacts, but it is rather the issue of the ps file handler than the file itself. You can avoid this behavior by asking Gnuplot to produce a simpler eps that won't fail on your favorite eps editor, or you change how you process eps.

### change the palette to something more simple

You can define the maximum number of different colors by the `maxcolors` option of the palette. This generates not more than `maxcolors` number of possible colors, but it is equidistant.

```
set terminal postscript portrait color enhanced 12
set o "discrete.eps"
set palette defined (-6.0 "#1B66B1",\
                     -4.8 "#2A85DF",\
                     -3.6 "#5FA3E7",\
                     -2.4 "#95C2EF",\
                     -1.2 "#C9E0F7",\
                     0.0 "#FFFFFF",\
                     1.2 "#F6D5CB",\
                     2.4 "#EDAB96",\
                     3.6 "#E48062",\
                     4.8 "#DC562E",\
                     6.0 "#AE3F1E") maxcolors 11
set samples 20
set isosamples 20
splot sin(sqrt(x**2+y**2))/sqrt(x**2+y**2) w pm3d
```

When inspecting the color bar, you can notice the small gap rendered on the png (but not in the eps) after I created the png using Inkscape:

[image]

### keep the original palette, but change the way you process eps

If you keep the original palette, it generates hundreds of color possibilities, but most of them will collide according to the step-like function you introduced in the color palette.

```
set terminal postscript portrait color enhanced 12
set o "discrete.eps"
set palette defined (-6.0 "#1B66B1",\
                     -4.8 "#1B66B1",\
                     -4.8 "#2A85DF",\
                     -3.6 "#2A85DF",\
                     -3.6 "#5FA3E7",\
                     -2.4 "#5FA3E7",\
                     -2.4 "#95C2EF",\
                     -1.2 "#95C2EF",\
                     -1.2 "#C9E0F7",\
                     -0.12 "#C9E0F7",\
                     -0.12 "#FFFFFF",\
                     0.12 "#FFFFFF",\
                     0.12 "#F6D5CB",\
                     1.2 "#F6D5CB",\
                     1.2 "#EDAB96",\
                     2.4 "#EDAB96",\
                     2.4 "#E48062",\
                     3.6 "#E48062",\
                     3.6 "#DC562E",\
                     4.8 "#DC562E",\
                     4.8 "#AE3F1E",\
                     6.0 "#AE3F1E")
set samples 20
set isosamples 20
splot sin(sqrt(x**2+y**2))/sqrt(x**2+y**2) w pm3d
set o
set term wxt
```

Open the eps using different editors to see how it looks like. Use gimp and you'll get something like the fig below.
[image]

If you use Inkscape first, which can handle eps natively, it can produce the artifacts.

You can convert the eps to pdf using ghostscript's ps2pdf.

Answer (score 1):

This is more a comment on the answer from DanielTuzes than it is a separate response.

The issue of possibly transparent, possibly off-color, artifacts at the boundary between two solid-fill rectangles is a recurring issue with PostScript/PDF rendering programs and viewers.

This is not really gnuplot's fault (the *.eps *can* be rendered correctly, it's just that many rendering utilities are glitchy).  However, there is a way in gnuplot to suppress these artifacts. In the development version and in the forthcoming gnuplot version 5.4.3 it is selected with a new keyword:

```
#gnuplot 5.4.3
set pm3d border retrace
```

Prior to this the same option existed but was undocumented and did not have a separate keyword:

```
#gnuplot versions prior to 5.4.3
set pm3d border lt -6
```

This work-around draws extras lines to cover the potential artifacts along fill boundaties, which has the drawback that it makes the output file larger.